# bitcoind reloads blockchain from scratch when it starts up?

Tags: bitcoind, synchronization, daemon

I have had my bitcoind turned off for a couple of months and I just turned it on again (bitcoind -daemon), and it seems to be reloading the entire block chain from scratch. Shouldn't it be loading only the blocks I am missing from the last two months? Why is it starting over from the beginning? Is there any way to get it to remember the blocks it already downloaded from before?

**UPDATE**

It seems to be increasing in blocks very rapidly, so possibly it is just reading through the blocks on disk and updating its memory?

Comment: Did you corrupt your directory `~/.bitcoin` in any way? Or did you add something like `txindex=1` to your config file? Short of these two events, as far as I understand it, `bitcoind` should not start over from the beginning.

Comment: @SvenWilliamson My machine is configured to operate like a full node.

Comment: "It seems to be reloading the entire chain from scratch" Can you elaborate on what makes you conclude this? How long does it take? What numbers for headers and blocks do you see in the `getblockchaininfo` RPC? Is it using a lot of CPU or I/O?